# Selecting just specific part of HTML with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, xmlhttprequest, queryselectall

I currently download an HTML from a website and I'm using "responseText" to get the HTML code, now I only want a specific part of it. How do you select a specific part of the HTML code with XMLHttpRequest? I already research doing it using Xpath or querySelectorAll, how do I do this practically and easily? Let say from the HTML code you wan't to select only --> div where id="home-members".

Thanks in advance!

This is the codes:

foobar.com/index.html:

```
..........
.....
<body>
..........
<div id="home-members">
    ........
    .....
</div>
....
</body>
```

My Traversal code:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
   url: "http://foobar.com/index.php",
   cache: false
}).done(function( html ) {
   var partial = $(html).find("home-members");
   $("#results").append( partial);
})
</script>

<body>
    <div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Which browsers do you target? Mozilla and IE 10 support `new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html')` to give you a HTML DOM document you could then query with `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to search the returned html. Something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false
}).done(function( html ) {
  var partial = $(html).find("div.dynamic-wrap.sidebar-wrap.clearfix");
  $("#results").append( partial);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've tried it, and nothing will show up in my div.results section.

Maybe it's because I don't really know jQuery well, can you give me an example working code? let's say the url is http://www.google.com  and you wan't to get the "text" from the search button?

thanks again.

Comment: Well that would be a same origin error unless Google has CORS enabled. Did you change the `#results` to be the id of the element you want the content to be added to? Have you tried to use a simple selector to see if it works?

Comment: Yes, I also tried simple selectory and it change my div#results content. I updated the post using your code.

Answer (score 0):

mm if i don't understand wrong...

responseText is a string so you could select parts of it using regEx but i think it could be not easy and hacked.

another solution could be.. putting the response text in a div using InnerHTML, so you can use standard javascripts selectors to take various elements. something like..

```
document.getElementById('structural_div').innerHTML = responseText;

var what_you_need = document.getElementById('structural_div').getElementById('id_of_element_you_need').className
```

instead of `getElementById('id_of_element_you_need')` you can get the element in the way you want, by class name, by tag name etc..

Hope to have helped you :)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for this.